# CUDA Kernel for copying array location from neighbour location

Tags: cuda

I have a cuda kernel that copies from i+1 th location to the ith location in a device array. The copying is not done from the locations whose index values are multiples of 32. [32]->[31] not copied, [64]->[63] not copied. This happens irrespective of the block size. How this could be resolved?
Here is the full program. No calls for syncthreads(). Still the problem exists.

```
#include <cstdio>
struct SodA { float *df0; size_t pitch; };

__global__ void stream_kernel (SodA dA1, SodA dA2, int M, int N);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int i, M=32, N=32;float *f0;
    SodA dA1, dA2;  
    dim3 blockSize = dim3(32,32);
    dim3 gridSize = dim3(1,1);
    f0 = (float *)malloc(M*N*sizeof(float));

    cudaMallocPitch((void **)&dA1.df0, &dA1.pitch, sizeof(float)*M, N);
    cudaMallocPitch((void **)&dA2.df0, &dA2.pitch, sizeof(float)*M, N);

    for (i=0; i<M*N; i++) f0[i] = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX; 
    cudaMemcpy2D((void *)dA1.df0, dA1.pitch, (void *)f0, sizeof(float)*M, sizeof(float)*M, N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    printf("\n");
    for(int i=28;i<70; i++) 
        printf("%5d ", i);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("\n");
    for(int i=28;i<70; i++)
        printf("%.3f ", f0[i]); 
    printf("\n\n");

    stream_kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(dA1, dA2, M, N); 
    cudaMemcpy2D( (void *)f0, sizeof(float)*M, (void *)dA2.df0, dA2.pitch,sizeof(float)*M, N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=28;i<70; i++) 
        printf("%.3f ", f0[i]);
    printf("\n\n");

    free(f0);cudaFree(dA2.df0);
    cudaFree(dA1.df0);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

__global__ void stream_kernel (SodA dA1, SodA dA2, int M, int N)
{
    int i, j, i2d; 

    i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    i2d = i + j * M;
    if (i2d>0) { dA2.df0[i2d-1] = dA1.df0[i2d];}
}
```

The output

```
   28    29    30    31    32    33    ....

0.999 0.218 0.513 0.839 0.613 0.296 0.638....
0.218 0.513 0.839 0.198 0.296 0.638 ....
```

Comment: It is impossible to say anything without seeing the kernel code in question, along with the necessary host code which would allow someone to compile and run it a see the problem you are asking about.

Comment: @Marco13: Thanks, but it is hardly a repro case. The pitched memory access looks strange, but without a definition of what `SodA`, who knows what is going wrong. The conditional `__syncthreads()` is also undefined behaviour, and the indexing is likely going out of bounds on the last thread performing the copy as well. But this is all guess work without a working example

Comment: @talonmies Yes, I also considered asking about further details (e.g. the defintion of `SodA` or the launch parameters), but ... The structure of `SodA` can (likely) be derived from the code (basically, a float pointer `df0` and an int `pitch`), and the launch parameter should not matter in this case, but the `syncthreads` is indeed a problem. Beyond that: I think that the condition may be wrong. E.g. for `M=3,N=3,rowSize=3`, using `i=4,j=2` would give `id2=4+2*3=10`, and thus `id2<M*N`, but it would still be invalid. It should probably be `if (i<M && j<N)`, but this is just a guess.

Comment: Uninformed guesswork isn't constructive. Which is why I don't indulge in it. It is a pretty simple proposition - provide a complete working repro case and you'll probably get help and an answer. Don't and you won't. The latter applies here. If I had the opportunity to vote to close this again, I would.

Comment: With cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy, the kernel does the copy correctly.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you are trying to do here. If the memory is pitched linear memory, then the (i-1) value in isn't guaranteed to be a valid value.  What you are seeing is to be expected. Why are you using pitched memory in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. In a 2D array stored in row major order, this kernel moves the (i,j)th position to its previous position. Since the array is pitched, as mentioned in the comments, the previous element of the first element in each row could not be found using -1 offset. This special case is handled by computing the last element in the previous array. I got the answer. Thanks.